# How to get aero themed windows and a task bar on Ubuntu 11.10?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, windows-xp, taskbar, aero

I know some themes that make all of ubuntu look like windows 7, but I just want the windows to be aero themed. How can I do this? Also, I want the Windows 7 taskbar (including the start orb) in ubuntu. Please don't suggest getting windows 7, because I can't. I'm new to ubuntu (Windows xp user), so I don't want to go into the command line. Finally, I had been thinking about using a program called ViStart. Will it work? Please answer!

Comment: Assuming [this](http://lee-soft.com/vistart/) is vistart, it is a closed-source Windows program, and won't work natively in Linux. You could try [wine](http://winehq.org), though.

Answer (score 1):

A quick search found [this](http://www.howtogeek.com/55985/how-to-make-ubuntu-linux-look-like-windows-7/). It gives instructions on how to download and install a theme to make Ubuntu look just like Windows 7. It does require the use of a terminal, but it tells you exactly what to type, and looks very quick and easy.

If you just want the commands, here they are:

```
cd ~/

sudo wget http://web.lib.sun.ac.za/ubuntu/files/help/theme/gnome/win7-setup.sh

sudo chmod 0755 ~/win7-setup.sh

~/win7-setup.sh

setup-win7-theme
```

Enter those in order in the terminal, pressing Enter between each one, and going through any waiting/popups in between. When you're done, it will have you log out and back in, and once you've done that the theme will be fully applied.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should install KDE (4.8, preferably), install the Win7.Lookalike icon theme, get GnoMenu and put it on the panel, and use the Icon-Only Task Manager plasmoid on your panel instead of the Task Manager.

Comment: Yea, (default) KDE is a lot closer to Windows (7) than (default) Gnome is, don't even mention Unity. Probably better/easier to just go with Kubuntu than trying to install KDE on Ubuntu, though.

Answer (score -3):

ViStart, i'm not sure if it works or not, on wine, since it's a Windows program, it doesn't work natively on Linux. But even if it works, it would be useless since everything in that kind of "Start Menu" is in a "*virtual*" (not really virtual, but kind of) windows machine by wine, it isn't compatible at all with everything on your linux desktop. So don't even try using it, using it on a linux desktop is... ridiculous to me ^^!
Don't try to get a taskbar or startmenu like windows 7 on linux, it's impossible because nobody would bother to do it, linux should be linux, not a windows clone.
If you don't like the things of your default ubuntu 11.10 (Unity), you could switch to another desktop evironment to get new tools, new widgets, new taskbar, runner, launcher, ect... Like a completely different OS (but actually linux anyways). There are many environments out there for you to choose: KDE, GNOME 3, , Enlightenment, Cinnamon, Xfce, LXDE... That's the power of freedom.

Comment: Just telling someone they should not even attempt to do what they are requesting information about simply because **you** do not personally like the idea, is not only **not** an answer, but is inappropriate in general.  Obviously since someone else has actually created a theme to make Ubuntu look like Windows 7, there are other people like this one who want this kind of thing.  So, since your answer isn't really an answer, it doesn't belong here.  **The power of Freedom** is that if you want to use Ubuntu and make it look like Windows 7, you have the freedom to do so.